# Sharing Video on Ubuntu

Tags: hd-video

I am brand new to Ubuntu.  I want to have my daughter-in-law share videos of our first grandson.  Can you send me instructions on how to have her upload videos so we can watch them?  Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to AskUbuntu! Did your daughter-in-law try an upload service that didn't work for you, or are you just asking what *should* work? If it's the first, could you name the upload service? Basically everything should work (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu can play every commonly-used video format. Simply have the videos uploaded in the way they were before you switched to Ubuntu. I really can't imagine a technology your daughter-in-law might upload to that wouldn't work. You may be asked to install a "video codec" or player, but Ubuntu will recognize and install the required software automatically.

If you do not know how to share videos to begin, I recommend uploading to [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/) and selecting the "Unlisted" option to keep the videos private. Then you can simply watch and share the videos through your internet browser.